# Degree of a field extension over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $f(x)=x^4-2x^2-1$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $t$ a root of $f$.Find the degree of the extension $ \mathbb{Q} [\sqrt{2},t]/ \mathbb{Q} $.

We know from eisenstein cretirion that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Can someone help me to prove this without finding the roots of $f$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do we know from Eisenstein criterion that $f$ is irreducible? What prime did you use?

Comment: take f(x+1) and p=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the $f$ splits in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ into $(x^2-1 + \sqrt2)(x^2 - 1 - \sqrt2)$. No matter which of these two factors we choose $t$ to be a root of, the degree $[\Bbb Q(t, \sqrt 2):\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)]$ is clearly not larger than $2$.

If we choose $t$ to be a root of $x^2 - 1 + \sqrt2$, then $t$ is not a real number, so $[\Bbb Q(t, \sqrt 2):\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)]$ cannot be $1$ and therefore must be $2$.

If we choose $t$ to be a root of $x^2 - 1 - \sqrt2$, then $[\Bbb Q(t, \sqrt 2):\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)]$ is still $2$, but it's not as immediate to see. The most straight-forward way is to assume that the degree is $1$ (i.e. that $t \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$, or in other words, $t = a + b\sqrt2$ for rational $a, b$) and derive a contradiction. We get 
$$
(a + b\sqrt2)^2 - 1 - \sqrt2 = 0\\
a^2 + 2b^2 - 1 + (2ab - 1)\sqrt2 = 0\\
a^2 + 2b^2 - 1 = 0 \quad \bigwedge \quad 2ab - 1 = 0\\
a^2 + 2b^2 -1 = 0\quad \bigwedge \quad a = \frac{1}{2b}\\
\left(\frac{1}{2b}\right)^2 + 2b^2 -1 = 0\\
\left(\frac{1}{2b}\right)^2 - 2 + 2b^2 = -1\\
\left(\frac{1}{2b} - 2b\right)^2 = -1
$$
which clearly isn't possible for rational $b$. Therefore we must have $[\Bbb Q(t, \sqrt 2):\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)] = 2$.

In any case, we get $[\Bbb Q(t, \sqrt 2), \Bbb Q] = 4$.

Comment: if we take $[Q(\sqrt{2},t):Q(t)].[Q(t):Q]=[Q(\sqrt{2},t):Q]$ do we find the same degree?

Comment: @capo Yes, and it's quite easy to show that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2, t) = \Bbb Q(t)$, so the first degree is $1$. However, the easiest way of showing that $[\Bbb Q(t):\Bbb Q]\neq 2$ is basically the above argument going via $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ anyways. So while the idea works, in practice it's not the easy way.

Comment: if we take for instance the extension $[Q(\sqrt{3},t):Q]$ ,then this extension (with the above polynomial) has degree greater than 4?

Comment: @capo I would expect it to have degree $8$.